# C - Beginner question, calling my print function wrong

Tags: c

Code isn't done, so variables like KWHPrice can be ignored.

When I'm trying to run my code only the first print is displayed correctly, if I enter let's say 3 4 6 2 5, I get 4194432 (address), is suspect it's because I'm referring to int smallest wrong, as it's both a variable in main and in the function, hence two different variables. I would like some guidance

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


#define MAX_SIZE 100 


void GET_LOWEST_PRICE(double KWHPrice[MAX_SIZE], int i, double num, double smallest);



int main(void){
int num, smallest;

 printf("\nEnter no of elements :");
   scanf("%d", &num);    

void GET_LOWEST_PRICE(double KWHPrice[MAX_SIZE], int i, double num, double smallest);

printf("\nSmallest Element : %d", smallest);

}



void GET_LOWEST_PRICE(double KWHPrice[MAX_SIZE], int i, double num, double smallest){
   
   for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
      scanf("%d", &KWHPrice[i]);
 
   
   smallest = KWHPrice[0];
 
   for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
      if (KWHPrice[i] < smallest) {
         smallest = KWHPrice[i];
      }
   
 
   }
   
}
```

Comment: You aren't calling `GET_LOWEST_PRICE()` in `main()` — you are redeclaring it.  Also, you can't get the smallest price from the function because you don't pass a pointer to it.  You need `double *smallest` as the argument if you're to get the smallest price back (and other changes to match).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I will give it a go, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You are redeclaring `GET_LOWEST_PRICE` in main. To use it you will need to call it with your specified parameters.

ex: `GET_LOWEST_PRICE(10.8, 1, 1.8, 0.2)`

Comment: What  if the input isn't fixed, can I somehow include the scanf in GET_LOWEST_PRICE()

Comment: Yeah, you can pass in your `num` variable into one of the parameters.

ex: `GET_LOWEST_PRICE(10.8, 1, num, 0.2)`

Comment: I think I get it, it's supposed to be multipole inputs, but I guess my %d is at issue aswell, thanks for your help